# Find value corresponding to maximum in other column

Tags: r, max, match, correspondence

I have a data frame similar to as follows:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y <- c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1)
df <- data.frame(x, y)
```

I want to find the value of `x` when `y` is at its maximum. I know that I can find the max of `y` with this:

`max(df$y)`

But I don't know how to match it, and I think there's probably a better way.

Comment: `with(df, x[which.max(y)])` or `df$x[which.max(df$y)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
# install.packages(dplyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    filter(x == max(y)) %>% # filter the data.frame to keep row where x is maximum
    select(x) # select column y
```

Alternatively to return a vector

```
df %>% 
    filter(x == max(y)) %>% 
    pull(x) # pull the variable y
```

using base R:

```
df[df$x == max(df$y), "x"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try indexing like this:

```
df$x[df$x == max(df$y)]
```